# C++11 Smart Pointer Make Functions for Variable Sized Objects

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, factory-method

Consider I have a class with no public constructor, but a static factory or builder method, and the size of the created object depends on the arguments passed to the factory (or builder).

Is there a way to create a shared (or unique) pointer to such an object using `std::make_shared` (or `std::make_unique`)?

For any suggested polymorphism, I prefer templates over virtual methods.

Comment: What do you mean by the "size" of the object? You can't have instances of the same class that differ in size.

Comment: "Size" is the byte length of the contiguous memory that is allocated when an object is constructed, and freed when it is destroyed.

Comment: Could you edit in some code showing how you're creating these objects *without* smart pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Consider I have a class with no public constructor ...
>
> Is there a way to create a shared (or unique) pointer to such an object using `std::make_shared` (or `std::make_unique`)?

There is no such way. `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique` require a public constructor.

Instead, you can create the shared (unique) pointer without the convenience "make" function:

```
// within the factory
return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(size));
```

---

PS. C++11 standard library has no `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an in-place factory method that will construct the object in a block of memory you provide it, plus a method that tells you how much space you'll need, you can do this.

I'm going to freely use C++14, add your own `typename` and `::type` if you really need C++11.

First we assume we have this:

```
struct some_args {
  // whatever
};
std::size_t how_big_is_X( some_args );
X* make_X( some_args, void* buffer );
```

with the above, I can do something functionally equivalent to `make_shared`.

```
template<std::size_t Sz, std::size_t align=alignof(void*)>
struct smart_buffer_t {
  void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;
  std::aligned_storage_t< Sz, align> data;
  template<class T, class...Args>
  T* emplace(Args&&...args) {
    return ctor( [&](void* pdata) {
      ::new( pdata ) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } );
  }
  template<class F>
  T* ctor( F&& f ) {
    std::forward<F>(f)( (void*)&data );
    dtor = [](void* ptr){
      static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T();
    };
    return static_cast<T*>((void*)&data);
  }
  ~smart_buffer_t() {
    if (dtor) dtor(&data);
  }
};

template<class T, std::size_t Sz, std::size_t Algn=alignof(void*), class F>
std::shared_ptr<T>
make_sized( F&& f ) {
  auto pbuff = std::make_shared<smart_buffer_t<Sz, Algn>>();
  T* r = pbuff->ctor( std::forward<F>(f) );
  return {r, pbuff}; // aliasing ctor
}
```

now we have:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
using pow_t = index_t< (1<<I) >;

std::shared_ptr<X>
make_shared_X( some_args args ) {
  std::size_t Sz = how_big_is_X(args);
  using pmaker = std::shared_ptr<X>(*)(some_args);
  using maker_maker = [](auto Sz){
    return +[](some_args args) {
      return make_sized<X, Sz>([&](void* ptr){
        return make_X(args, ptr);
      });
    };
  };
  static const pmaker table[] = {
    maker_maker(pow_t<0>{}),
    maker_maker(pow_t<1>{}),
    maker_maker(pow_t<2>{}),
    // ...
    maker_maker(pow_t<63>{}), // assuming 64 bit size_t.
  };
  std::size_t i = 0;
  while(Sz > (1<<i))
    ++i;
  return table[i](args);
}
```

or somesuch.

Code not tested.  It allocates the power of 2 at or larger than your args demand.  But the object is constructed at in the same allocation as the reference counting block.

Any series instead of powers of 2 can be used, but the table size must be large enough to handle the largest possible return value from `how_big_is_X`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> buildObjectWithSize(std::size_t size)  {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>{T::buildObject(size)};
}

class MyObject {
public:
    static MyObject* buildObject(std::size_t size) {
        return new MyObject(size);
    }

    int& operator[](int i) {
        return int_vector[i];
    }
private:
    MyObject(std::size_t size)
    : int_vector(size) {
    }

    std::vector<int> int_vector;
};

int main () {
    constexpr unsigned INT_VECTOR_SIZE{3U};

    std::unique_ptr<MyObject> my_object_up{buildObjectWithSize<MyObject>(INT_VECTOR_SIZE)};

    (*my_object_up.get())[1] = 5;
    std::cout << (*my_object_up.get())[1] << '\n';

    MyObject &my_object_ref = *my_object_up.get();
    my_object_ref[2] = 3;
    std::cout << my_object_ref[2] << '\n';
}
```